# How to printf an exclamation mark in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I need to printf a simple script and redirect the output to a file, but when I do this:

```
printf "#!/bin/bash\ntouch /tmp/1234567890_$RUN" > /tmp/password-change-script_$RUN.sh
```

I get this error:

bash: !/bin/bash\ntouch: event not found

If I escape the exclamation mark:

```
printf "#\!/bin/bash\ntouch /tmp/1234567890_$RUN" > /tmp/password-change-script_$RUN.sh
```

Then the escape character is still present in the file.

```
cat /tmp/password-change-script_$RUN.sh
#\!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/1234567890_111
```

By the way, in this particular case, the #!/bin/bash MUST be in the file. For some reason the binary file that executes the script won't read the file otherwise.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `!` character is expanded in double-quoted strings, but not in single-quoted strings.

```
printf '#!/bin/bash\ntouch /tmp/1234567890_'"$RUN"
```

It's also not expanded when it appears by itself or at the end of a word; this isn't as clean but:

```
printf "#%c/bin/bash\ntouch /tmp/1234567890_$RUN" !
```

You can also temporarily turn off history substitution by (temporarily) setting `$histchars` to the empty string; this turns off the special treatment of `!`:

```
histchars=
printf "#!/bin/bash\ntouch /tmp/1234567890_$RUN"
unset histchars
```

Or you can execute the `printf` command in a script rather than interactively (history substitution is on by default only for interactive shells).

Comment: @David: I've updated my answer with a couple more alternatives.

Answer (score 15):

Try doing this :

```
printf "\041"
```

This is the octal ASCII representation of `!` character

See

```
man ascii
```

---

Another solution :

```
(
    set +o histexpand 
    printf "!"
)
```

(the parenthesis are used to change terminal setting in a *subshell*, so the change is temporary)

See

```
help set
set -o
```

Comment: Actually, this only works in single quotes, and so does printf '!'.

Comment: See my second solution in my edited post

Comment: This works both with single & double quotes as well, like in my post